# Easily enabling/disabling issue tracking of all repositories on Gogs

Tags: git, gogs

I want to enable/disable issue tracking of all the repositories easily. Whereas Gogs' web interface only allows enabling/disabling issue tracking option of a single repository at a time.

It is not possible enabling/disabling issue tracking of repositories under the same organization, either.

Because I have a lot of repositories, I need an easier way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage to enable/disable issue tracking feature of all or some(under the same organization) repositories. To achieve that, I used [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl) and executed following SQL commands on SQLite database:

```
-- Disable issue tracking of all repositories
UPDATE repository SET enable_issues = 0 WHERE enable_issues = 1;

-- Enable issue tracking of all repositories
UPDATE repository SET enable_issues = 1 WHERE enable_issues = 0;

-- Disable issue tracking of all repositories under TESTPROJECT organization 
UPDATE repository SET enable_issues = 0 WHERE owner_id IN (SELECT id FROM user WHERE name='TESTPROJECT');

-- Enable issue tracking of all repositories under TESTPROJECT organization 
UPDATE repository SET enable_issues = 1 WHERE owner_id IN (SELECT id FROM user WHERE name='TESTPROJECT');
```